# Downloading wine-x64 when opening Software Center

Tags: unity, wine, software-center

Whenever I open Ubuntu Software Center or the "About my computer", the program seems to freeze and a small Window pops up saying
"Downloading wine-x64-unity3d-installer (7MiB)"

It takes about a minute to download, and then Software Center (or Details) unfreezes and I can resume what I wanted to do. The next time I turn on the program, exact same problem occurs. Why is this happening? Does Ubuntu Software Center run on Windows libraries and isn't native to Linux (what a ridiculous idea)

I tried purging wine and anything that has to do with wine. The only thing left on my computer is a package called "wine-staging". I am unable to remove this package as DPKG tells me that the package has dependencies.

What is causing this issue?

Comment: A stupid suggestion, but `sudo apt-get install -f` fixes a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the cause of this were remaining wine "addons". The solution was to enter:

> "sudo dpkg --purge pipelight-multi gnome-exe-thumbnailer"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's an annoying side effect from having pipelight enabled. You can disable that plugin or you can wait for it to fully install.